# Order and reverse order by group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort a table in descending order based on the maximum value of id for each name but each set of rows by name itself should be sorted in ascending order.

I have sorted my table descending on id.

```
id  | name | other cloumns
----|------|---------------
11  | yv   |
10  | abc  |
9   | abc  |
8   | zx   |
7   | tv   |
6   | tv   |
5   | tv   |
4   | yv   |
3   | yv   |
```

I want it to be sorted as

```
id  | name | other cloumns
----|------|---------------
3   | yv   | /*yv is on top because it had max id i.e. 11*/
4   | yv   |
11  | yv   |
9   | abc  | /*abc is second because it has 10*/
10  | abc  |
8   | zx   | /*zx is third because it has 8*/
5   | tv   | /*tv is fourth because it has 7*/
6   | tv   |
7   | tv   |
```

How can I do that? I am using MySQL

Comment: I am sorting myself with SELECT and ORDER BY id

Comment: Not sure what you intend when you say "by group." It looks like you want to sort by the `name` column in descending order, and then the id column in ascending. Is that right?

Comment: @vch sorry, I mean name

Comment: you keep editing the question to change the data. are you sure it's correct now?

Comment: @vch no you can see in result that names are not ordered. The 'yv' has max id so it is on top of results. Then 'abc' because it has 10

Comment: @vch I am only editing the question details. I am not editing the data

Comment: I can't really determine an order based on your data. Neither id nor name are in any particular order. How would you describe it?

Comment: @vch I added comments to explain. Rows with same name are sorted in ascending withing themselves and they are all sorted asc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
order by name desc, id asc
```

You can put multiple keys into the `order by`.  The first key is used for the sorting.  When the key values are the same, the second gets used, and so on.

EDIT:

I see, you want the names with the smallest id first.  For this, use a `join`:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select name, max(id) as maxid
      from table t
      group by name
     ) n
     on t.name = n.name
order by n.maxid, t.name, t.id
```

Comment: Name are not sorted. Rows are sorted by ids. Each set of rows with same names should be sorted in asc. While they all should be sorted in descending.

Comment: @LifeH2O . . . I think the edited version is what you want.  Your question starts out "I want to sort a table in descending order based on name", but that is not what you seem to want.  You seem to want "I want to sort a table in descending order based on the maximum value of id for each name."

Comment: Yes, That is lot a better explanation.

Comment: You can use a correlated subquery in the `order by` if you like, but one more join shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can't reproduce the requested result: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb2b7/2/0) What am I missing. (Yeah, of course, I do see, your answer has still been accepted.)

Comment: Didn't realize earlier, simply adding "DESC" to the "ORDER BY" does fix it. And it makes the solution more stringent overall. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can combine **Order by** with **Union** like this:

```
select * from (select * from table1 order by id where name='yv')
  union all
select * from (select * from table1 order by id where name='abc')
  union all
select * from (select * from table1 order by id where name='zx')
  union all
select * from (select * from table1 order by id where name='tv')
```

**EDIT**

```
select tt.id,tt.name from 
(select max(t.id) tid,t.name from table1 t group by t.name order by tid desc) tb 
join (select * from table1 tb1 order by tb1.id) tt
on tb.name=tt.name
```

Comment: Any way without putting the value of name in query?

Comment: You have to put the values if you hadn't a special pattern for sorting

Comment: I mean you need to specify: on base of which logic you want to sort your data

Comment: I have added comments in my question details to explain the order.

Comment: Great, now it's understandable, I'm working on it, I'll post, it's not defecult

Comment: I am unable to test it on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Sorry I corrected it, the problem was with group by clause, can you pleaze test it again?

Comment: I am unable to make it work in sqlfiddle. It is table1 is not found

Answer (score 1):

This seems to deliver the requested:

```
SELECT sampleData.id, sampleData.name
FROM
  sampleData
JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        @rowNum := @rowNum + 1 rowNumber
        , name
        , MAX(sampleData.id)
      FROM    sampleData, (SELECT @rowNum := 0) s
      GROUP BY name
      ORDER BY MAX(sampleData.id)
    ) orderedName
  ON sampleData.name = orderedName.name
ORDER BY orderedName.rowNumber, sampleData.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fffa5/8/0)

Comment: Yeah - didn't see originallly, how adding "DESC" to the sort order would make Gordon's solution complete…